# Is it possible to change the date of my Etihad return flight?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, etihad

I traveled to Thailand with Etihad Airways. I want to go back earlier than planned. The one-way tickets I would get are as expensive as my original ticket, so I hope to get something less expensive.

Is there a way to change the date of my return flight?

Comment: Have you called Ethihad and asked about changing your date?  Your options are dictated by your fare bucket rules.

Comment: what type of tickets have you booked? the answer should be in the T&C of your tickets.

Answer (score 6):

Contact your travel agent or, if you don't have one, Etihad. Terms and conditions regarding changes are highly variable but most non-flex fares (not all!) do allow a change, for a fee (usually). Often in the region of $100 to $200.

If your ticket is fully-flex then you should expect no fee.

ANY change will of course be subject to seat availability which, since I assume you are considering an imminent change, could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Ethihad and it turned out that changing the ticket would cost me as much as a new ticket from where I am currently staying. I took the latter option.